# Center the content of a mat-expansion-panel in Angular material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to center the content of my angular material expansion panel. I initially just tried surrounding my content in a div and style it with align-content: center and align-items: center. But that doesn't seem to work. The content seems locked on the left side. My guess is there's some angular material class I need to override the styling with !important. But I'm not sure which.

```css
.centered-content{
  align-content: center
  align-content: center
}
```

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <!-- #docregion basic-panel -->
  <!-- #docregion hide-toggle -->
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <!-- #enddocregion hide-toggle -->
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="centered-content">
      <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <!-- #enddocregion basic-panel -->


</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the `mat-expansion-panel-body` class. You have to do it with `::ng-deep` pseudo-class because of the [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation):

```css
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mheq71?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

```css
.centered-content{
  text-align: center;
}
```

This centers that p-tag in a js fiddle, however there could be other things preventing this from working.

If you create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily help you, without having to all create an application to reproduce this.

Also, the example css in your question can not possibly work, since it is missing semicolons.

I will take a look at your code and update the answer if you do...